# Routed event handlers drag drop information

Tags: wpf, routed-events

If I register a class handler like so:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
typeof(ListBoxItem),
DropEvent,
new RoutedEventHandler(OnListBoxItemDropEvent));
```

The following method signature is expected:

```
private void OnListBoxItemDropEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

The standard Drop method signature is the following:

```
private void Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
```

i.e. it gives you access to the `DragEventArgs e`

Is there a way for me to access the `DragEventArgs e` when registering a routed event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a `DragEventHandler` (instead of a `RoutedEventHandler`)?:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
                typeof(ListBoxItem),
                DropEvent,
                new DragEventHandler(Drop));
```